# Binding error in linq to sql

Tags: linq-to-sql, data-binding

how do I solve this problem?

Exception :

> This causes two bindings in the collection to bind to the same property.
>     Parameter name: binding

Code :

```
var q = Movie_List.Actors.Where(a => a.Actor_Name == Snametxt.Text);

            Acttxt.DataBindings.Add("Text", q, "Actor_Name");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve problem finally.

you must remove binding after binding data .

```
            try
            {
                Acttxt.DataBindings.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
```

before bind control too database write this code for any control.